# Visualize a Word2Vec model using Embedding Projector

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, data-visualization, word2vec, gensim

What is the best way to visualize a Word2Vec model using TensorFlow's Embedding Projector?
is there a way to export the Word2Vec model's vectors to the format that Embedding Projector expects? or is there a built in function in tensorflow for that?

Thanks!

Comment: You can take a look at [this](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/1035). It seems people have written a script for this. I did not try it though

Comment: Are you using gensim or pure tensorflow?

Answer (score 6):

Save your model using

```py
model = Word2Vec(sentences)
model.wv.save_word2vec_format('model_name')
```

And then convert the model to the input files required by Embedding Projector:

```sh
python -m gensim.scripts.word2vec2tensor --input model_name --output model_name
```

This will produce both: *model_name_tensor.tsv* and *model_name_metadata.tsv*

This last script was introduced in a [PR](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/pull/1051) from the issue linked in a comment in your original question.